# initial and last date of change

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ID's, dates and values witch are the results of periodic tests.
I can find the latest test with the according result.
But I need also the initial date since when the same result is marked.

```
ID  Date       Value
01  2015-01-01  2
01  2015-02-01  3
01  2015-03-01  3
01  2015-04-01  2
01  2015-05-01  2
01  2015-06-01  1
01  2015-07-01  3
01  2015-08-01  3
01  2015-09-01  3
```

So here the last date and result for ID 01 are **2015-09-01** and **3**
The initial date that I also need is **2015-07-01** as that is the initial dat of the last serie with value **3**

How can I write this query?

I get the last date and score by ID using this query:

```
select * from tblScores s 
join (
    select id, max(Date) as MaxDate 
    from tblScores group by id
) Q on s.id = q.id s.date = q.maxdate
```

Comment: What's the table's name?

Comment: tblScores.
the last date and score by ID I gets as follows: 
    select *
    from tblScores s
    join (select id, max(Date) as MaxDate
    from tblScores 
    group by id) Q on s.id = q.id s.date = q.maxdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These queries with variables simulates the `ROW_NUMBER()` Window Function (not supported by MySQL).

#### Query 1 ID

If you are working with only 1 `ID` at a time like in you sample, this query can be used:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , @n := CASE WHEN @value <> Value THEN @n +1 ELSE @n END as n   
        , @value := Value 
    FROM data1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @value, @n := 0) v
    ORDER BY Date DESC
) as x
WHERE n = 0
GROUP BY ID
;
```

#### Output:

```
ID |              MIN(Date) |                   MAX(Date)
 1 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 | September, 01 2015 00:00:00
```

#### Query several IDs

If you want the same result for several IDs, this query can be used:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Date), MAX(Date)
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , @n := CASE 
            WHEN @ID <> ID THEN 1
            WHEN @value <> Value THEN @n +1 
            ELSE @n END as n   
        , @value := Value 
        , @ID := ID 
    FROM data2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id, @value, @n := 0) v
    ORDER BY ID, Date DESC
) as x
WHERE n = 1
GROUP BY ID
;
```

#### Output:

```
ID |              MIN(Date) |                   MAX(Date)
 1 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 | September, 01 2015 00:00:00
 2 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |      July, 03 2015 00:00:00
```

This [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46227f/4/0) contains both samples and queries.

#### Data used:

```
INSERT INTO data2
    (`ID`, `Date`, `Value`)
VALUES
    (01, '2015-01-01', 2),
    (01, '2015-02-01', 3),
    (01, '2015-03-01', 3),
    (01, '2015-04-01', 2),
    (01, '2015-05-01', 2),
    (01, '2015-06-01', 1),
    (01, '2015-07-01', 3),
    (01, '2015-08-01', 3),
    (01, '2015-09-01', 3),
    (02, '2015-01-01', 2),
    (02, '2015-02-01', 3),
    (02, '2015-03-01', 3),
    (02, '2015-04-01', 2),
    (02, '2015-05-01', 2),
    (02, '2015-06-01', 1),
    (02, '2015-07-01', 3),
    (02, '2015-07-02', 3),
    (02, '2015-07-03', 3)
;
```

Table `data1` only contains the first rows where `ID=1` (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46227f/4/0)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does the job!
Is there a way to get the according value other then joining it with itself on ID and max(date)?

Comment: There is no join aside from the cross join with variables ? Are you talking of the group by ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I found it myself.
I wanted the correct Value also but I can simply add it in the select to get the correct value (in the example 3 for both).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. This is basically a subquery with a group by on it.

Comment: It was to quick to post my comment. When I add also the value in the upper select (SELECT ID, MIN(Date), MAX(Date),value) then I get also the correct Value of the last test for each ID. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I am already drinking to it 